# The program gives an error in the middle of the work

Tags: python, selenium

When scraping a site, everything goes well until the program gives this error after scrolling down a few times

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)
```

```py
def gsrc(A):
    [list_src.add(src.get_attribute("src"))  for src in A]

for i in range(100):
    b.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    A=b.find_elements_by_css_selector('.KL4Bh img')
    gsrc(A)
    time.sleep(5)
```

what is the reason?

Comment: Can you post your relevant code, not just an error?

Comment: Generally it means that the element you are trying to access no more presented there or was changed

Comment: Right, the most common situation is you have defined an element, navigated to another page, then tried to call that element again. If you share your code maybe we can identify why it happens and how to fix.

Comment: I added time.sleep(4) to the program and it worked longer but it crashed again

Comment: Use PDB module to know where you have gone wrong

Comment: @PCM This isn't the full error trace, it should be obvious which line caused the error in my experience. anyway yes, PDB = PLEASE DE BUG!

Comment: It's not a delay issue....

Comment: my code ..........

Comment: I guess the error probably comes from this line `[list_src.add(src.get_attribute("src"))  for src in A]` but I can't tell. Can you share the page HTML so that we may reproduce this behavior?

Comment: thankd bro,I fixed it using try and except,,The bug was in src.get_attribute ("src")